# Setting correct resolution for Background image

Tags: android

I want to set a background image into my app. I tried to set my background image in my xml file with android:background(im using a relative layout) but it seems the image was scaled and doesn't appear to be correct or in its original form.

Let's take an example if I want to display it on a 480x800 screen and only on portrait mode. Should I also produce a background image with a resolution of 480x800?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you should. Keep in mind that there are three different directories to put your drawables in (ldpi, mdpi and hdpi drawables directories) put your background images in the appropriate directory according to pixel density and the app will chose the appropriate one to use according to the device it is run on.

Comment: When I tried to make a background image with a resolution 480x800 it is actually scaled. I think 480x800 is the screen dimension not the size of the application window itself. If there are 3 different directories then what is the resolution requirement for ldpi? mdpi? and hdpi?

Comment: you are confusing resolution and density. you can have a 480X800 resolution screen that is ldpi(low dinsity, fewer pixels per inch), mdpi(medium density) or hdpi(high density, many pixels per inch). The 480x800 hdpi device would be much smaller than the 480x800 ldpi device. according to android dev: "When adding support for multiple screens, applications do not work directly with resolution; applications should be concerned only with screen size and density, as specified by the generalized size and density groups."

Comment: the densities are as follows: ldpi=120dpi, mdpi=160dpi, hdpi=240dpi. Maybe have a read through the official website for supporting multiple screens and this may become clearer. Here's a link `http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html`

Comment: Thanks I will check this one out and get back if there is something unclear.